# Okhttp stops working after updating android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, okhttp

I've an Android app using retrofit 2 and okhttp for its json requests. everything was going fine until android studio(AS) oferred me the update from 3.9.6 to 4.1
The update is done easily inside the AS and it also updates the gradle plugin.

Once the update was finished I rebuild and compiled a new aab, then i notice the new file generated was 100kb smaller than the previous one (altough no code or assets changes were made, only the IDE version updated)... then i release on google play and download it in my test device (real phone). It didn't work. The app opens but it is not able to perform any okhttp request

I tried to run inside AS emulator -> it worked fine.
I tried to run in the emulator with minifyEnabled true shrinkResources true -> it worked fine

so i added to the code several debug calls in order to let me know exaclty until what line the app was working.... and i got.

```
try {
               okHttpClient.newCall(new Request.Builder().get().url("https://www.google.com").build()).execute();
               return true;
           } catch (Exception e) {
               return false;
           }
```

this is a little snippet i use to test if user has internet connection.
No exception is thrown, no value is returned, the call simple dive into the okhttp api and never come back...

So i want to let clear: no code was changed, no api was updated, no r8 rules was changed
the only thing changed was the AS updated from 3.9.6 to 4.1 and some mandatory gradle plugin updated as well
after that the signed aab built got 100kb smaller and this very weird behavior started happening...

I've already tried EVERYTHING i can, but still no idea how to solve. does anyone ever face a similar problem or have idea what to do?

there are my imports

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.13.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }

    //retrofit
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }

 
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0-RC1"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0') {
        exclude group: "com.google.code.gson", module: "gson"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've already tried EVERYTHING i can, but still no idea how to solve. does anyone ever face a similar problem or have idea what to do?

Yes, everyone faces these problems.  It's part of the learning process of being a developer.  Stop focusing on this particular problem with this library for a minute and ask why you are stuck and how to get unstuck. If you reported this to a library maintainer this is what they would need to do, which is why they would ask for a clean reproduction.

Firstly read http://sscce.org/ and understand what it means and why the above question isn't getting answers.  It's not a clean reproduction, it's a few random lines of code.

Then ask a a colleague to help you use a debugger, where is it stuck, what are the threads doing or waiting on.

Use the features of the library e.g. add an OkHttp Event Listener https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/.

Going back the SSCCE example, make a small example project reproducing the issue and post it to a temporary github project, then report that as a bug to OkHttp project.  They can just check out the project and run it to reproduce then.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to fetch data using a retrofit. Getting 400 on release build. My model was like the following:

```
data class ContentIdAddRQ(
    @SerializedName("contentId")
    val contentId: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("contentType")
    val contentType: String? = "VOD",
)
```

Then I tried adding @Keep annotation to my Model file as shown below:

```
@Keep
data class ContentIdAddRQ(
    @SerializedName("contentId")
    val contentId: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("contentType")
    val contentType: String? = "VOD",
)
```